# Magento - Expected Delivery date on Transactional Email

Tags: magento, email, transactional-email

We need to add "Expected delivery date" in Transnational Email of Magento. Can anyone please tell me the predefined variable( or code) for expected delivery date in magento. If there are no predefined variable in magento for expected delivery date. Please tell me the right solution for this.

Thanks

Comment: hello,which module are using for this?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to extract it from order or shipping object then send it to transactional email variable and then you can get that variable in your email template.eb if your variable is var1 then you can get in email template like {{var var1}}.if you can explain it more i can define it more way
Thank you